# How to convert CGridView into PDF

Tags: yii, pdf-generation, fpdf, cgridview

I tried the extension pdf-grid with FPDF, but cannot support for CSqlDataProvider completely, if i hide the header of the Grid then its works. But i wants to use with header. Is there any idea to get the header of the Grid or is there any other extensions for Cgridview with Csqldataprovider

Comment: Try this extension instead: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/

Comment: Try PhpExcel Extension:http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpexcel/